# How to play Any YouTube video play in full screen in android app

Tags: android, youtube, android-mediaplayer

I am making an Android app which is related to YouTube video. I saw in my android apps that will not play full screen. How to play any YouTube video in full screen?
Please help me.

Comment: you can check this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want a fancy way of doing that (with a little bit more effort) and without opening the Native Youtube App or Youtube in a browser, you can use [Youtube Data Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). If you decide to do it this way, I can edit this with some code snippets that might be helpfull :)

**EDIT**

```
public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {
private YoutubePlayer mPlayer;
private static String VIDEO_ID;

private final static String API_KEY = "your_api_key";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();


    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

            if (!wasRestored) {
                mPlayer = player;
                mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                mPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                mPlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                mPlayer.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            // YouTube error
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }

    });

    return rootView;
}
```

this is to make the video as a fragment of your activity(since you work in an app you probably need it this way). It will go straight to full screen(if you don't want to, comment mPlayer.setFullscreen(true) ) and will auto play your video. Hope this will help you

For a simpler way you could simple get [this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/youtube-android-player-api-example) which is using the YoutubeBaseActivity as the superclass. All you need is the youtube video ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply please help me i can do any hard work

Comment: where i paste this code mainActivity or any new activity?

Comment: I would not recommend you to copy-paste it. Take a look at it, understand it and try to adapt it into your application. As I said, if you want this to work in a fragment of your activity, you can use the code I gave you, otherwise take a look at that link I gave you

Comment: there is error generate in                                                                            
                                                                                       FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();                                                            and red in root view how to fixed that?

Comment: Can you edit the post, and put the code you are working on ?

Comment: i edit this code but i cant solve:-   FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

Comment: View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_layout, container, false);

add this right after onCreateView()

Comment: finally last transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout,youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

Comment: And what is the problem with that ? Read please the error, I cannot guess

Comment: finally last transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout,youTubePlayerFragment).commit();     show that cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)'     how to fixed this

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID"));
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: that is just for specific video

Comment: you have asked for 'how to play in full screen' and I gave you the answer for that

Answer (score 2):

try this  **Youtube v4.1.47**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID"));
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: that is only for specific video i want to make for any video which user want to play